# Odoo13-CE: Module: Sales: How can I style quotation-pdf and quotation-customer preview

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

Module: Sales: Quotations
I would like to change style of text and colour of buttons in the customer preview.
I would like to add padding and margin to the pdf-file.

What are the options to do these changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To customize the customer preview you need to alter the [sale portal templates](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/sale/views/sale_portal_templates.xml).

`Download` and `Print` button are defined in [sale_order_portal_template](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/sale/views/sale_portal_templates.xml#L143) template:

```
<div class="o_download_pdf btn-toolbar flex-sm-nowrap">
    <div class="btn-group flex-grow-1 mr-1 mb-1">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-block o_download_btn" t-att-href="sale_order.get_portal_url(report_type='pdf', download=True)" title="Download">
            <i class="fa fa-download"/>
            Download
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group flex-grow-1 mb-1">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-block o_print_btn o_portal_invoice_print" t-att-href="sale_order.get_portal_url(report_type='pdf')"
           id="print_invoice_report" title="Print" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-print"/>
            Print
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

To change button text style and color, you can alter the `class` or `style` attribute, In the following example we use `btn-primary` instead of `btn-secondary` class:

```
<template id="sale_order_portal_template" name="My Sales Orders" inherit_id="sale.sale_order_portal_template">
    <xpath expr="//a[hasclass('o_download_btn')]" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="class">btn btn-primary btn-block o_download_btn</attribute>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

The page content is defined inside a div with id [quote_content](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/sale/views/sale_portal_templates.xml#L201)

Comment: Thank you, @Kenly! What about PDF file? Is there a way to customize it?

Comment: Yes of course. Alter the [report_saleorder_document](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/sale/report/sale_report_templates.xml#L3) template